# View list of bluetooth devices in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth

I have a small bluetooth project in kotlin.  The code for it is below:

```
   var mArrayAdapter: ArrayAdapter<String>? = null
val bluetoothAdapter: BluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()
var myList: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf<String>()
var devices = ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>()
var devicesMap = HashMap<String, BluetoothDevice>()

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {

    private val REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1000

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        findViewById<View>(R.id.btn_scan).setOnClickListener(this)
        checkBluetoothStatus()
        val filter = IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND)
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter)
        mArrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.dialog_select_device)



    }


    private val receiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {

        override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
            val action: String? = intent.action
            when(action) {
                BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND -> {

                    val device: BluetoothDevice =
                        intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE)
                    val deviceName = device.name
                     myList.add(deviceName)
                }
            }
        }
    }


    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        when (v?.id) {
            R.id.btn_scan ->
                startScan()
        }
    }


    fun startScan() {
        if (BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().startDiscovery()) {

            val myToast = Toast.makeText(this, myList.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)

            myToast.show()
        }
    }

}
```

When a user clicks a button, I want to be able to see a list of other bluetooth devices (which I thought the onReceive method would enable me to do).  So I'm adding device names to the myList variable, which I'm then displaying in a toast. But at the moment when they click, nothing comes up.  Grateful for your advice.